# How to calculate the inverse of a Hessian matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Hello does anybody know how to calculate the inverse of a Hessian matrix ? A link to a solved example would be awesome. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The same way as the inverse of any other matrix I suppose?

Comment: You are right. I somehow assumed that the row manipulation did not apply to a Hessian matrix. Thanks !!!